# Imported Embedded Framework into Watch Extension

Tags: xcode, swift, watchos-2

I've created an embedded framework containing some swift classes and am able to import and use this successfully in my main app using the import statement. The functions I'm using are marked public and everything works just fine in the main app.

> import FrameworkNameKit

However, when I add a watchos2 target when I try to import the framework into the Watch Extension Xcode can't find the framework and I always get the 'No such module' error. I'm trying to import into the InterfaceController.swift file if that helps.

The entire project is written is Swift and I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta.

Has anyone managed to do this successfully? I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did you ever end up solving this? I'm having a very similar problem and haven't been able to work it out. Thought I'd check before I spent a day or two investigating the Lister project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't find this actually documented anywhere, but if you take a look at Apple's ["Lister" project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Introduction/Intro.html) for watchOS, it seems you have to have a separate framework built for the watchOS SDK in order to include that framework into a watchOS 2.0 extension and include any shared code in both the iOS and watchOS framework targets.

Comment: What about a custom CoreData framework for shared use between main app and watch extension?

Comment: @AceGreen: Yeah, I'm assuming the same is true. Share the code between the two frameworks and build two separate ones: one for watchOS and another for iOS.

Comment: What is the point of having a framework if you can't share it between iOS and watchOS? This is not the same to add the source code to both the iOS and watchOS app?

Comment: @mxb: I had the same thought, and almost added it as a snarky addendum to my initial answer, but thought better of it. :)

My guess is that you might share the frameworks between multiple different watch or iOS apps? For example, Apple has a single "Clock" app on iOS that interacts with multiple watch apps that might share a framework.

Comment: @Arclite makes sense if you have multiple apps on the same platforms. It is confusing that you can share the same framework between iOS app and, say, Today Extension but not with Watch Extension. Not sure it was the same with watchOS 1. I feel little confused on this whole matter.

Comment: @mxb: It wasn't the same with watchOS 1, because watchOS 1 extensions ran on iOS, not watchOS.

Comment: Is there an example of how you do it in watchos2? Can't find any concrete example on the net.